# Angular eventListener from Directive

Tags: angularjs

I have directive, essentially a button, that should only show on certain conditions. It uses `addEventListener('scroll')` to capture the scroll of a `<ion-content>` element in the containing page. This works fine for one page/view but when navigating to another page/view the scroll event is not fired?

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('Fmpclient')
  .directive('fmpRefreshButton', ['$window', '$ionicScrollDelegate', 'RefreshButtonService', function ($window, $ionicScrollDelegate, RefreshButtonService) {

        var hideDelayTime = 3500;
        var isButtonVisible = false;
        var lastYPos = 0;    // store the last Y Position
        var timerId = null;  // store a setTimeout id for later use
        var $scrollEl = null;
        var refreshButton = null;

/* __ code snipped for brevity __ */

        /**
          Work out the direction of scroll so we can
          either hide or show the refresh button according to AC
          @method onScroll
          @public
        */
        function onScroll () {
          var scrollTop = $ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top;

          if(scrollTop > lastYPos) {
            // Scrolling DOWN - hide refresh button
            hideRefreshButton();
          } else {
            // Scrolling UP - show refresh button
            shouldRefreshFeed();
          }
          // Store the last Y position to determine
          // direction of scroll on next iteration
          lastYPos = scrollTop;
        }

        /**
          Setup directive elements on init
          @method init
          @public
        */
        function init (){
          console.log('directive::init()');

          RefreshButtonService.setRefreshFeed(false);

          $scrollEl = document.getElementById('ionContentScroll');

          if($scrollEl){
            $scrollEl.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
          }
        }

        function _link(scope, element) {
          refreshButton = element[0];

          init();
        }

        return {
            templateUrl: 'app/app/refresh-button/refresh-button.directive.html',
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: true,
            link: _link,
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: My first guess is that you are using getElementById('ionContentScroll'). This  would be a reference to the first instance of the element with id='iconContentScroll' and there can only be one of these as getElementBbyId works on the global DOM.  If you are going to use this on multiple pages (and remember Angular is a single-page app) then this element id should be unique everywhere that it is used and it should be passed in as a parameter in the directive so it is unique for each usage.

Comment: Scott, Thank you! - I have been totally code blind. Of course Angular is a single-page app!

After passing in a 'unique id' to the directive it works as it should.

In the directive scope:
```scope: {
  scrollElement: '='
},```

In the directive template:

```scroll-element="ionFeedScroll"```

And...
```scroll-element="ionAnotherScroll"```

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Scott, in the comment above, the solution to my rather trivial problem was to pass in the id as a parameter to the directive to ensure the id can be unique for each usage:

In the Directive scope:

```
scope: {
   scrollElement: '='
},
```

and passed in on the Directive template:

```
<my-directive scroll-element="ionFeedScroll">
```